# RelativeLayout positioning not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hi,

I am trying to design a layout that has no dependency on screen size. Actually I am designing a sample layout in which there is a large size add in the center of screen. There is a text in the center of upper remaining area and lower remaining part. The xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ads_layout_large"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ads_layout_large"
        android:background="#fff000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/exit_enjoyed_text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ads_layout_large"
        android:background="#fff000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/exit_enjoyed_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, it is working on upper part, the text is exactly in the center of the remaining area, but the lower `TextView` has covered half of the screen, can you please help me find the mistake? Or any other way to design the same?

Answer (score 1):

I think here is your problem :

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

setting your TextView height to fill_parent cause your textview extend to reach it's parent size , use wrap_content or static value like "30dp" instead

Comment: I need to keep it in center of remaining part.
The same thing is working on the upper part but not for the below.

Comment: for centering Text in textview use android:gravity="center|center_vertical"  and if you want textview get centered in it's parent use layout_gravity="center|center_vertical".hope this help

Comment: Actually i want to divide my screen in three parts:
1> The Middle part with 300dp x 250dp
2> The Upper Remaining part.
3> The Lower Remaining part.
And i think it is quit simple in android but how is the main question.

Comment: so you can use linear layout(nested layout) for each part then aligning your items in each part ,i think your relative layout work is not right.